# border-radius - not smooth... why?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a rounded corner button using border radius but currently, the corners are not looking as they are supposed to.

Is there something wrong w this line of code?

```
<li style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:8px">
      <!-- Login modal -->
    <button class="btn-xs btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style = "margin-top: 10px; border-radius: 30%; background-color: white;">
      Log in
    </button>
</li>
```

Comment: A screenshot might help us determine what you're expecting and how the outcome is...

Comment: You're using a percentage and it's not fully browser compatible. Depends what you were using to test it on. Any reason *why* you are using percentages?

Comment: new to css, thought percentage should work fine. i tried pixels as suggested, and it worked. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You gave the border radius in (%), give the border Radius in pixel. It will work as you want.

```html
<li style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:8px">
<!-- Login modal -->
  <button class="btn-xs btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style = "margin-top: 10px; border-radius: 30px; background-color: white;">
    Log in
  </button>
</li>
```

Comment: `%` is fine have you tried playing around with percentages though `30%` is a lot?

Answer (score 0):

To get the rounded look, simply increase the pixel size on the border
radius.

Create a custom class name it as `round`. We will use this class to
   modify the buttons provided by Bootstrap by default.

```
< button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg round"> Log In < /button>
```

Add CSS modification to the custom class

```
.round {
  border-radius: 24px;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/76ggnx8u/4/)